# Can posts_nav_link show post titles?

Tags: pagination

I have an index.php page that is only displaying 1 post at a time with a query.

(found this code online, but it does work)

```
$page  = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

// if we are paging
if ($page == 1) {
    query_posts('order=DESC&posts_per_page=1&paged=$page');
} else {
    $numposts  = get_option('posts_per_page');

// work out offset
$offset = (($page -1) * $numposts); // i.e. page 2 - 1 = 1 * 10 (10 for the number of posts)

query_posts("&order=DESC&offset=$offset&paged=$page&showposts=$numposts");
```

}

This correctly shows one post per page, and it displays the navigation on the bottom of my template when I put a `<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>` in there.

Is there anyway to change the "Next Page" and "Previous Page" links to be the titles of the posts themselves?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well to your question this should work.

```
<?php

global $paged;

if($paged > 1) {

$previous_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ;

$prev_post_title = get_the_title($previous_post->ID);

} else {

$prev_post_title = null;

}

$next_post = get_adjacent_post(true, '', true) ;

$next_post_title = get_the_title($next_post->ID);

posts_nav_link('&bull;', $prev_post_title, $next_post_title);

?>
```

Just copy and paste in someplace of your index.php.

Comment: For some reason this is getting the adjacent Pages for me? I have a "Blog" page that is using a blog.php template.